# Recovering Matlab performance scaling via vectorization

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm trying to run a simple particle trajectory simulation, in which I propagate ~10,000 particles through a potential energy surface. In other programs like Matlab, I of course get a huge speedup when I vectorize my code such that all particles take time steps together, and I apply Newton's laws to entire vectors holding the positions/ velocities. In Mathematica, I'm trying to use this same method but see that the simulation time scales exactly linearly with the number of particles I put in. Is this typical, or should Mathematica also benefit from vectorized code?

```
singlestep[rv_, dt_, dUx_, dUy_, dUz_, nf_] :=

 Module[{fx, fy, fz, xx, yy, zz, xnew, ynew, znew, vx, vy, vz, vxnew, 
   vynew, vznew},
  xx = rv[[;; , 1]]; yy = rv[[;; , 2]]; zz = rv[[;; , 3]];
  vx = rv[[;; , 4]]; vy = rv[[;; , 5]]; vz = rv[[;; , 6]];
  Do[
   fx = -dUx /@ Transpose@{xx, yy, zz};
   fy = -dUy /@ Transpose@{xx, yy, zz};
   fz = -dUz /@ Transpose@{xx, yy, zz};
   xx += vx* dt + 1/2*fx/M*dt^2;
   yy += vy *dt + 1/2*fy/M*dt^2;
   zz += vz* dt + 1/2*fz/M*dt^2;
   vx += fx/M*dt;
   vy += fy/M*dt;
   vz += fz/M*dt,
   {nn, 1, nf}];
  xnew = xx; ynew = yy; znew = zz;
  vxnew = vx; vynew = vy; vznew = vz;
  {xnew, ynew, znew, vxnew, vynew, vznew}]
```

nf is a variable referring to how many "fine" steps are taken (but for this test I am setting it to 1). dUx/y/z are interpolating functions that contain the force components as a function of position. rv is an array that contains the 3 positions and 3 velocity components from the previous steps, so for each particle is size 1x6. As I add more particles by increasing the size of rv from 1x6 to nx6, I see the code slow down exactly proportional to n.

Comment: You should get big speed ups. We really can't say what's going on unless you post an example.

Comment: @C.E. `Listable` is not exactly the same as vectorization. Many, but not all, mathematical functions have internal vectorized versions that are automatically called if you set up your code and data properly.

Comment: I've edited the above to include a code example.

Comment: First, `InterpolatingFunction` is one of the functions not vectorized; however it is listable, and `dUx @ Transpose@{xx, yy, zz}` should save a some time.  Also, your're transposing `{xx, yy, zz}` three times each loop-step. You should be able to do it once outside the loop and use the transposed array (probably would need to transpose `{vx, vy, vz}` too); or not even transpose. Isn't `rv[[ ;; , 1;;3]]` == Transpose@{xx, yy, zz}`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I removed that from my comment almost immediately after posting, but I knew – knew – that someone would get me for it. You are right.

Comment: @C.E. Some non-vectorized things are improved by Listability. So it's not completely wrong, either. It is complicated enough that expressing oneself accurately is not easy, and I don't know of a nice guide to vectorization.

Comment: With these comments, I get about a factor of 2x speed up, but the scaling with array size is still poor. Is there anything to address this fact? Or should I just not expect to reproduce the speed I can get in Matlab?

Comment: Scaling depends on choice of algorithm, not the language, unless Matlab is performing some form of introspection to auto-optimize. What is `M` in your code? You can probably get good enough speed without improving your algorithm simply via `Compile` (assuming the `dU`s are compileable)

Comment: Do you have sample data? That'll help people give you a better answer.

Comment: M is the particle mass (roughly 10^-26 kg).

Answer (score 5):

> In Mathematica, I'm trying to use this same method but see that the
>   simulation time scales exactly linearly with the number of particles I
>   put in.

What do you expect, bro? Increasing the number of flops linearly will inevitably lead to linear growth in (pure) computation time. Maybe you see some sublinear scaling of the runtime in Matlab because of the hidden JIT compiler which may introduce a certain overhead.

Back to the code. Currently, I see three issues that may lead to slowdown: 1. Excessive use of `Transpose`. This coordinate-wise processing of vectors is so matlabish. It makes code unreadible and seldomly leads to any improvements. 2. `Map` in the form of `/@`, and 3. the `Do` (but that is really less an issue).

As you do not provide `dUx`, `dUy`, `dUz`, I use the gradient of a potential in the following:

This is the code:

```
Quiet[Block[{x, xx},
   xx = Table[x[[i]], {i, 1, 3}];
   f = x \[Function] Evaluate[-Exp[-x.x/2]];
   gradf = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], {xx, 1}]];

   dUx = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], xx[[1]]]];
   dUy = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], xx[[2]]]];
   dUz = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], xx[[3]]]];

   With[{code = gradf[xx]},
    cgradf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
      code,
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True
      ]
    ];
   ]];

step = r \[Function] With[{f = -cgradf[r[[1]]]}, 
    {r[[1]] + r[[2]] dt + (0.5 dt^2/M) f, r[[2]] + (dt/M) f}
   ];
```

This is some example data

```
n = 100000;
p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
M = 1.;
dt = 0.1;
```

And this is the actual test with timings

```
stepcount = 100;
rv = Join[p, v, 2];
bla = singlestep[rv, dt, dUx, dUy, dUz, stepcount]; // AbsoluteTiming
blubb = Nest[step, {p, v}, stepcount]; // AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[Transpose@Join[blubb[[1]], blubb[[2]], 2] - bla]]
```

> {5.26767, Null}
>
> {0.719926, Null}
>
> 7.34968*10^-14

Comment: This looks great! I've tried updating this example so that I can use it with an interpolating function, and I find that the Compile-d version is in that case 10x slower than not compiling. See here:
g = Table[-Exp[-x^2/2], {x, -2, 2, .01}];
gg = ListInterpolation[g, {-2, 2}];
Quiet[Block[{x},
  f = x \[Function] Evaluate[gg[x]];
  gradf = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];
  With[{code = gradf[x]},
   cgradf = 
    Compile[{{x, _Real}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]];
  ]
 ]

Comment: @B.Solver Not only is `InterpolatingFunction` not vectorized, it is not [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions). As a result, `Compile` wastes a lot of time with call back to the main kernel.